# django-elasticsearch-dsl unable to filter with mulitiple model fields

Tags: django, elasticsearch

models.py

```
class PostJob(models.Model):
    job_title                   = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    job_description             = models.TextField()
    key_skills                  = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.job_title
```

documents.py

```
from django_elasticsearch_dsl import DocType, Index
from .models import PostJob

jobs = Index('jobs')

@jobs.doc_type
class JobsDocument(DocType):
    class Meta:
        model = PostJob

        fields = [
            'job_title',
            'job_description',
            'key_skills',
        ]
```

views.py

```
from .documents import JobsDocument

def search_jobs(request):
    q = request.GET.get('q')
    if q is None:
        return JsonResponse({"code":500,"msg":"query sting not found"})
    if q:
        Q = JobsDocument.search().query
        jobs = Q("match", key_skills=q) or Q("match", job_title=q)
        lst=[]
        dict ={}
        for i in jobs:
            dict["job_title"]                   = i.job_title
            dict["description"]                 = i.job_description
            dict["key_skills"]                  = i.key_skills
            lst.append(dict.copy())
    return JsonResponse(lst,safe=False)
```

in django using 'django-elasticsearch-dsl'  i am trying to search with multiple model fields.

here i wants to filter with multiple fields with **key_skills** and **job_title**
but it is coming with only **key_skills** but doesn't matches with **job_description**

for **job_title** if my **job_title** job **python developer** it is not coming if i am searching only **developer**. it is coming when i am searching **python developer** completely with white space

Please have a look into it..

Comment: What is the mapping of index? If a field is keyword then it is not analyzed and hence stored as it is. Therefore **python developer** will not be analyzed and split into **python** and **developer**. If you want it to be analyzed the data type of the field should be `text`.

Comment: okk.. then tell me how it will be

Comment: Share the index mapping. I will suggest the changes required.

Comment: i have shared all the codes .. where is index maping??

Comment: Assuming your elasticsearch is running on localhost on port 9200, index name is `test` use the following to get mapping: `localhost::9200/test/_mappings?pretty`